# how to get the calendar email id in android version 8.1?

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I'm trying to get the email ID of the calendar using the calendar runtime permission. It worked perfectly in android version 6.1. and so I started testing in version 8.1.

After installing the application, it will ask for permission to read contacts and I asked the permission, but while trying to login to the app it outputs an error in the logcat `needs read contact permission`. I cannot understand why it is happening.

I need to get the calendar email id to insert the same data in google calendar. so I'm trying to get the read contact permission.

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Permissioncheck.java**

```
public class Permissioncheck extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR = 123;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 123;

    public static int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE_CHATHEAD = 1234;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = Permissioncheck.this;
        boolean result = checkPermission();
        if (result)
        {
            writeCalendarEvent();
        }
    }

    private void writeCalendarEvent()
    {

        Log.d(Utils.LogTag, "lst_StartService -> Utils.canDrawOverlays(Main.this): " + Utils.canDrawOverlays(Permissioncheck.this));
        if(Utils.canDrawOverlays(Permissioncheck.this))
        {
            checkPermission_Contact();
            startService();
        } else {
            requestPermission(OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE_CHATHEAD);
        }
    }

    public void startService()
    {
        boolean results = checkPermission_Contact();
        if (results)
        {
            Intent k = new Intent(context, Login.class);
            startActivity(k);
        }

    }

    private void needPermissionDialog(final int requestCode)
    {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(Permissioncheck.this);
        builder.setMessage("You need to allow permission");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                requestPermission(requestCode);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void requestPermission(int requestCode)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE_CHATHEAD)
        {
            if (!Utils.canDrawOverlays(Permissioncheck.this))
            {
                needPermissionDialog(requestCode);
            } else {
                startService();
            }
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public boolean checkPermission()
    {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("Write calendar permission is necessary to write event!!!");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public boolean checkPermission_Contact()
    {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("Write calendar permission is necessary to write event!!!");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

                } return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    writeCalendarEvent();
                } else {
                    //code for deny
                }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**New_Schedule_Calendar.java** //here i am trying to get calendar email id

```
int calenderId = -1;
String calenderEmaillAddress = possibleEmail;
String[] projection = new String[]{
    CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
    CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME
};

ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), projection, //here i am getting error
CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + "=? and (" +
CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME + "=? or " +
CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME + "=?)",
new String[]{calenderEmaillAddress, calenderEmaillAddress,
calenderEmaillAddress}, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

    if (cursor.getString(1).equals(calenderEmaillAddress)) {

        calenderId = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
}
cal_id=calenderId;
```

**logcat error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 6789
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.Schedule_Delete}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2 uri content://com.android.calendar/calendars from pid=6789, uid=10212 requires android.permission.READ_CALENDAR, or grantUriPermission()
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2974)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2 uri content://com.android.calendar/calendars from pid=6789, uid=10212 requires android.permission.READ_CALENDAR, or grantUriPermission()
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2021)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:418)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:760)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:710)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:668)
at com.example.myapplication.New_Schedule_Calendar.writeCalendarEvent(New_Schedule_Calendar.java:111)
at com.example.myapplication.New_Schedule_Calendar.Start_Write(New_Schedule_Calendar.java:50)
at com.example.myapplication.Schedule_Delete.onCreate(Schedule_Delete.java:44)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1222)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

I want to get the email id and insert the data in google calendar.

**App crashes:**

[image: App crashes]

**all permission given:**

[image: App permissions screen]

**Asking for access to contacts**

[image: Asking for contacts permissions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've mis-read the warning you got on LogCat, it says:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ... requires android.permission.**READ_CALENDAR** ...

The reason for this is that you're asking only for WRITE_CALENDAR permission but not READ_CALENDAR permission, before Android 8, if you were granted any permission, you were also automatically granted all the permissions within the same permissions group, the behavior had since been modified and you need to specify all the permissions you need.

So simply change

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

to:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{permission.WRITE_CALENDAR, permission.READ_CALENDAR}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

Also, I think it would be wise to give different request codes to `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR` and `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS`.